# Java error Cannot resolve method 'map' in 'List'

Tags: java, list, dictionary, crud

I'm trying to get working backend in Java for CRUD app. I am using Java 1.8. I used the following implementation of findByName(name) [below]. Intellij says that there is error, because "Cannot resolve method 'map' in 'List'". Does it means that Java does have map method? How can I overcome this. I have been trying to add before something like stream etc. but it does not help. I also would like to have device returned in findByName and with some tried solution the error was moving from map method to return device. I would be grateful for help, it is keeping me awake long in the night because I cannot finish.

```
return deviceRepository.findByName(name).map(device -> {
        LOG.info("Reading device with name " + name + " from database.");
        return device;
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new DeviceNotFoundException("The device with the name " + name + " couldn't be found in the database."));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does it means that Java does have map method?

No.  It means that the `List` interface does not a `map` method.  You can check the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for yourself to confirm this.

> How can I overcome this.

So it looks like your code is intended to search the list, then either write a log message and return an element, or throw an exception.

There is a pretty fundamental problem with this.  The `findByName(name)` method can clearly return more than one "device".  So your code has to decide what to do in that case.

Here is one possible solution:

```
List<Device> found = deviceRepository.findByName(name);
if (found.size() == 0) {
    throw new DeviceNotFoundException("The device with the name " + name + 
                                      " couldn't be found in the database.");
} else if (found.size() > 1) {
    throw new DeviceNotFoundException("Multiple devices with name " + name + 
                                      " found in the database.");
} else {
    LOG.info("Reading device with name " + name + " from database.");
    return found.get(0);
}
```

Other possibilities would be to ignore the case where multiple devices have the same name (and just return the first), or change the `findByName` API to return only one device.

Answer (score 1):

Java's lists do not have a map method and never did. It's also extremely odd for a list to have a method named `orElseThrow` - is that supposed to be `ifEmptyThrow`, perhaps? That doesn't exist either, but at least that makes sense. Or is `findByName` an operation that may or may not find a result, and `map` is supposed to be a no-op if there is no result, and `orElseThrow` is to be invoked if no result is found?

'deviceRepository', nor findByName, is recognizable, which is not helping.

If `findByName` returns a `List<Device>`, java doesn't make it simple to try to stream your way into 'if empty'.

If findByName is supposed to return 1 or 0 elements, if it returns an Optional, your code as pasted will work. Which makes me assume it doesn't.

That leaves: Stop treating the back of your shoe as a universal tool. It's a nice shoe and all, and great for walking, but not for nails. This is how to do it. Plain. Simple.

```
List<Device> devices = deviceRepository.findByName(name);
if (devices.isEmpty()) throw new DeviceNotFoundException("The device with name + " name + " couldn't be found in the database");
LOG.info("Reading device with name {} from the database", name");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that has helped. You are right about shoe analogy, I'm working to obtain better approach.